# How to enable "Install" or "Open" Button in facebook messenger in a "yet-to-launch" ios App for Testing

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an iOS app under development [Not yet launched]

And i want to get the following "Open" button visible on it while sharing the "from my app" via facebook messenger using FBSDKMessengerSharer:

[image: Open button in flipboard]

Facebook SDK

What i have done is the following:

As per Facebook's guidelines for Optimized integration.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios#optimized_integration

I have put .plist entries for facebook app ids, my own app id, URL schemes etc. 
i confirm the when i type my scheme://, it open up my app.
Facebook developer console on developer.facebook.com has correct entries for the app/bundle.

I have added myself and another user as test users as per the guidelines and Facebook have clearly written this is testable without submitting the app.

And then i have the following pieces of code for sharing in the app:

```
   func Share(){
        let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "Sample")!
        let opts : FBSDKMessengerShareOptions = FBSDKMessengerShareOptions()
        opts.contextOverride = cContext
        FBSDKMessengerSharer.shareImage(image, withOptions: opts)
    }
```

And the following for enabling optimized sharing in AppDelegate:

```
func application(app: UIApplication,
openURL url: NSURL,
options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    print("Called OpenURL")

    let h = FBSDKMessengerURLHandler()
    let a = "com.appcompany-new.name"
    if h.canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "temp://abc.xyz"), sourceApplication: a) {
        h.openURL(NSURL(string: "temp://abc.xyz"), sourceApplication: a)
    }
    return true
    }

func messengerURLHandler(messengerURLHandler : FBSDKMessengerURLHandler,didHandleOpenFromComposerWithContext context : FBSDKMessengerURLHandlerOpenFromComposerContext) {
     cContext = context
     print("Called Open from composer")
}
```

I donot see any button, the Open, Install or Reply button even now. What am i missing?

Comment: Use the apple id from an app which already exists on your Facebook App configuration, even if it's not yours.

Comment: This worked, thanks !!